# Improving FPS issues during raids

Tags: blade-and-soul

I have noticed me as well as many other players get a ton of performance and FPS issues (lag, freezes, etc) when they are part of a raid on a world boss (blackwrym, poh, mm). Are there any settings I can use to help alleviate this issue other than `CTRL + F` to hide player characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found settings myself to solve this issue, but I've found that it really helps if you zoom in your character when fighting the boss. Not a lot but much better experience than playing with all of those lost frames